# Tivoli Common Reporting Installation fails on Linux for missing prerequisites on Workload Scheduler

Tags: linux, workload-scheduler, tivoli-work-scheduler

For Linux operating system, Tivoli Common Reporting installation fails for missing prerequisites. The error message is the following:

> CRIMA1217E: A problem occurred during the execution of the /opt/IBM/JazzSM/install/reporting_services/tcrWrapperInstall.xml file.
>   Two defects have been opened to Jazz for Service Management development team.

Answer (score 0):

to circumvent the problem, install the following libraries:

- libpng16-16-1.6.13-2.4.1.i586.rpm
- openmotif-libs-32bit-2.3.4-25.3.x86_64.rpm
- openmotif-libs-2.3.4-25.3.x86_64.rpm
- openmotif22-libs-32bit-2.2.4-189.1.x86_64.rpm
- openmotif22-libs-2.2.4-189.1.x86_64.rpm